# Understanding memory addresses and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I received the following question on one of my practice problemswhere it says to determine what is printed by this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int ids[3] = {100,200,300};
    int *salary, salary1, salary2, *salary3;
    salary1 = ids[0] * ids[1];
    salary = &ids[1] ;
    salary2 = *(ids+1)* *(ids+2);
    salary3 = ids+2;
    printf("*salary = %d\nsalary1 = %d\n", *salary, salary1);
    printf("salary2 = %d\nsalary3 = %p\n", salary2, salary3);
}
```

I am a bit confused about this code. Firstly, in line 4:

```
    int *salary, salary1, salary2, *salary3;
```

Why is there an asterisk at the beginning of `salary3` if an asterisk was already used in the beginning of  the line?

Secondly when it says:

```
    salary1 = ids[0] * ids[1];
```

how are we supposed to determine the value of `salary1` when we don't know the value of `ids[1]`?

Comment: The `*` only applies to the variable right after it, not all the variables on the line.

Comment: Because it is not `int* salary` etc, but `int *salary` etc. The `*` qualifies the variable, not the type.

Answer (score 2):

> why is there an asterisk at the beginning of salary3 if an asterisk was already used in the beginning of the line?

The asterisk means the next variable is a pointer. It's the same as:

```
int *salary;
int salary1;
int salary2;
int *salary3;
```

but on one line.

> how are we supposed to determine the value of salary1 when we don't know the value of ids[1]?

But you do know the value of ids[1]. It's 200.

Comment: I know the value of ids[0] which is 2000, but not ids[1]

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed no, `ids[0]` is 100. Look at the array `int ids[3] = {100,200,300};` which defines `ids[0]` as 100, `ids[1]` as 200, `ids[2]` as 300.

Comment: oh my bad, i miss read that part. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, C declaration syntax is a bit confusing

```
int *x, y;
```

Means x is a pointer to an int, y is an int. That's such a source of confusion that virtually every style guide forbids it.

This

```
  int ids[3] = {100,200,300};
```

declares an array. ids[0] = 100, ids[1] = 200, ids[2] = 300. It's only really possible to match subscripts to array contents by eye when arrays are small. So this isn't a normal use of arrays. Either you have large read-only tables in global memory, or you create an array at runtime and fill it. However there shouldn't be an issue is ids[1] holding 200, that's how C array syntax works.